# How do I create a initial population from a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with a list of words. I want to input those words as my initial population of 100. I have around 200 to total words. I am not sure if I would use import random or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to clearly understand the concept of a test population, and then work through a tutorial or documentation of the `random` package.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  We expect you to complete this research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

I use `df.sample` for tasks like this.  For example:

```
data = ['stargaze', 'stephanotis', 'twelfth', 'speedup', 'harness', 'pole',
       'seagull', 'examination', 'enforceable', 'fescue', 'trumpery',
       'mow', 'Marvin', 'important', 'monastic', 'shark', 'Sophoclean',
       'Bella', 'modicum', 'corpse', 'insuppressible', 'Lancelot',
       'redstart', 'Emory', 'place', 'Kristin', 'q', 'heathen', 'nasal',
       'Constantinople', 'Alameda', 'lonesome', 'thong', 'spline',
       'mayonnaise', 'smile', 'hasty', 'camilla', 'perpendicular', 'writ',
       'berate', 'poplin', 'Martian', 'seventieth', 'grief', 'doorknob',
       'quicksand', 'Pawtucket', 'mercury', 'loris', 'here', 'emolument',
       'dynasty', 'woodrow', 'tramway', 'Ralph', 'package', 'coverall',
       'Werner', 'ordinal', 'lead', 'fibrin', 'Lancashire', 'elusive',
       'taste', 'Christ', 'whom', 'Roberta', 'virus', 'jostle',
       'fidelity', 'cell', 'slice', 'witch', 'Antioch', 'Kelvin',
       'audiovisual', 'end', 'jumble', 'dental', 'scrounge', 'onus',
       'picosecond', 'squint', 'Stromberg', 'beacon', 'Byrne',
       'extenuate', 'fasciculate', 'thunderstorm', 'Longfellow',
       'Goldwater', 'Moloch', 'seethe', 'antarctic', 'mouthful',
       'condominium', 'abduct', 'burbank', 'Sancho', 'estrus', 'guardian',
       'buckeye', 'orthography', 'noble', 'commissary', 'cutout', 'new',
       'walkout', 'Chungking', 'Breton', 'svelte', 'ore', 'persecutory',
       'lycopodium', 'Bali', 'deflect', 'accusative', 'Perle', 'Scranton',
       'diminish', 'awl', 'bilateral', 'triptych', 'inflorescent',
       'Ptolemy', 'academician', 'gravitometer', 'integer', 'fluffy',
       'ameliorate', 'thigh', 'infamous', 'Harvey', 'vacuole',
       'competitor', 'filth', 'refrain', 'schoolgirl', 'hepatitis',
       'Northrop', 'lodgepole', 'infelicity', 'slap', 'Helene',
       'evaluate', 'sanicle', 'Bellatrix', 'regurgitate', 'glen',
       'multifarious', 'triumph', 'talkative', 'acrophobia',
       'lexicographer', 'enunciable', 'birthplace', 'Stamford',
       'monastery', 'Zaire', 'tenacity', 'prologue', 'colloquial', 'owly',
       'scam', 'summer', 'valeur', 'capsule', 'Koppers', 'photogenic',
       'legerdemain', 'Heusen', 'symposium', 'jalopy', 'myoglobin',
       'Ellsworth', 'preemptor', 'Euphrates', 'wore', 'Middletown',
       'griffin', 'pansy', 'warfare', 'grub', 'repugnant', 'playa',
       'deliverymen', 'homestead', 'midnight', 'brainchild', 'churchyard',
       'frolicking', 'periphery', 'size', 'immersion', 'Greece',
       'through', 'uppercut', 'pro', 'col']


df = pd.DataFrame(data={"words":data})
df_init = df.sample(n=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your exact question? Do you want to randomly select 100 items (words) from a list of 200 items, which is stored as a .txt file? If so, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

with open("word_list.txt", "r") as word_list:
    words = word_list.readlines()

initial_population = np.random.choice(words, 4)
```

I would recommend, however, to use the approach mentioned by anon01.